# Mostrar en tiempo real el ancho del body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy buscando mostrar en tiempo real el ancho del body con jquery, tengo lo siguiente hecho:

```
<div class="currentDiv">
<label><b>Width:</b> <span id="widthval"></span></label>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#widthval').html($('body').width());
        $('body').on('resize', function() {
            $('#widthval').html($('body').width());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Funciona bien a medias, los valores se manejan bien, pero solo se actualizan cuando actualizado la pagina, verán, cuando se cambia el tamaño de la ventana del navegador tambien se cambia el tamaño del body, pero, lo que busco no es el tamaño de la ventana, sino del body, en fin, creo que al codigo lo unico que le falta es que muestre en el respectivo span los valores en tiempo real cuando se redimensiona el body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me pregunto por qué simplemente no usas `document` en lugar de `'body'` para obtener el ancho y el evento resize de `window`

Con el onresize clásico:

```
window.onresize = function (){
    $('#widthval').html($(document).width())
}
```

Con jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", function (){
    $('#widthval').html($(document).width())
})
```

Probé ambos códigos y me funcionan muy bien, el valor se actualiza solo, haciendo zum, cambiando el tamaño de la ventana y cambiando el tamaño del apartado de herramientas para desarrolladores. Puedes usar `$(document).ready` solo para realizar la inicialización y mostrar un valor desde el momento en que finalizó la carga del contenido si quieres.

Comment: Con todo respeto Mateo, no lo uso porque simplemente no lo conocia, si ando en busca de una respuesta es porque no he encontrado una solución factible, pero tu respuesta ha funcionado bien, gracias.

Comment: De nada, ahí te dejé una segunda solución y formulé mejor la solución. Para que uses la que más te guste. Cabe mencionar que no está demás saber de Javascript además de otras utilidades como lo son jQuery.